# forking php process and tying to specific web user

Tags: php, fork, process-management

I have a web app that has a few processes that can take up to 10 minutes to run.  Sometimes these processes are triggered by a user and they need the output as it is processed.

> For instance, the user is looking for
>   a few records that they need.  The
>   click the button to retrieve the
>   records (this is the part that can
>   take 10 minutes).  They can continue
>   to work on other things but when they
>   click back to view the returns, it is
>   updated as the records are downloaded
>   into the system.

Right now, the user is locked while the process runs.  I know about pcntl_fork() to fork a child process so that the user doesn't have to wait until the long process completes.

I was wondering if it's possible to tie that forked process to the specific user that triggered the request in a `$_SESSION` variable so that I can update the user when the process is complete.  Also, is this the best way to update a user on a long-running process?

Comment: I don't think `pcntl_fork` should be used in that context. Forking processes and multi-threaded web servers are known to be problematic. For web applications, you can have asynchronous updates sent to the browser using AJAX instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [gearman](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/gearmanclient.jobstatus.php) fits your needs. Look at this sample code, taken from the doc :

```
<?php

/* create our object */
$gmclient= new GearmanClient();

/* add the default server */
$gmclient->addServer();

/* run reverse client */
$job_handle = $gmclient->doBackground("reverse", "this is a test");

if ($gmclient->returnCode() != GEARMAN_SUCCESS)
{
  echo "bad return code\n";
  exit;
}

$done = false;
do
{
   sleep(3);
   $stat = $gmclient->jobStatus($job_handle);
   if (!$stat[0]) // the job is known so it is not done
      $done = true;
   echo "Running: " . ($stat[1] ? "true" : "false") . ", numerator: " . $stat[2] . ", denomintor: " . $stat[3] . "\n";
}
while(!$done);

echo "done!\n";

?>
```

If you store the `$job_handle` in the session, you can adapt the sample to make a control script.

Comment: awesome, I knew there was probably a better way, but I've never heard of Gearman before.